# How to serve site in one Docker container through a separate nginx container?

Tags: php, docker, nginx, docker-compose, centos7

I'm trying to create an easily deployed docker container (or set of containers) that will allow myself and other developers to code locally with an environment that matches our server environment.

I've succeeded in deploying a container with the appropriate OS and PHP versions, containing a volume that currently contains a boiler plate Laravel project.  It correctly pulls in the code, reflecting changes made to the external code base.

I'm also generating an nginx container (though ideally I'd like to get that down to one container in future) .  This presents the "Welcome to nginx!" message when I navigate to http://localhost:8080/ .

My knowledge of nginx is absolutely minimal, however, and is insufficient to serve the Laravel project in my other container.  It could be available and I am just unaware of the correct routing, but I think I've ruled this out.

I've not had to ask many questions before, as I've almost always been able to determine an answer with resources, but this is a new area of responsibility for me, please excuse me if the problem is obvious or rudimentary.

My original example was built off the docker image `php:7.1.8-apache` and served beautifully, but it uses a different OS to my requirements as well as the wrong version of PHP.

I tried combining images, hoping that layers would be the answer to my problem, but subsequent layers overwrote the OS of my original layer.  I'm not sure if I can accrue layers more discretely.

So now I am at the point where I am using the OS image as a base and then applying yum commands to install PHP.  Inside the container, the OS and PHP versions are perfect, and the code is present.

I feel like I'm almost there but I just cannot find out how to access the generic Laravel project in my browser and test the code changes as they are applied.

**Update**
I've updated the files to match the answer below, as well as fixing a problem I noticed; The default.conf file was being copied into the primary docker, rather than the nginx one.  Combining this fix with the answer below, I am now getting a 502 Bad Gateway error when I navigate to http://localhost:8080/ .

Laravel's index.php is located in \public, I've tried updating the index reference in default.conf to match this but with no luck.

The docker attachment details the following error when trying to load http://localhost:8080/ , instead of the welcome to nginx screen :
[error] 6#6: *24 connect() failed (111: Connection refused) while connecting to upstream, client: 172.22.0.1, server: , request: "GET / HTTP/1.1", upstream: "http://172.22.0.2:80/", host: "localhost:8080"

Neither the access.log nor error.log have any details logged when hitting the address.

docker-composer.yml

```
version: '3'
services:
  app:
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: .docker/primary/Dockerfile
    image: base-docker
    container_name: primarydocker
    #    ports:
    #      - 8080:80
    volumes:
      - .:/srv/jumbledown
    restart: unless-stopped
    tty: true
    networks:
      - draft-network
  webserver:
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: .docker/nginx/Dockerfile
    container_name: webserver
    ports:
      - "8080:80"
      - "443:443"
    links:
      - app
    networks:
      - draft-network
    restart: unless-stopped
    tty: true

#Docker Networks
networks:
  draft-network:
    driver: bridge
```

Dockerfile

```
FROM centos:7

RUN yum -y install epel-release yum-utils \
    && yum -y install http://rpms.remirepo.net/enterprise/remi-release-7.rpm \
    && yum-config-manager --enable remi-php71 \
    && yum -y install php php-common php-opcache php-mcrypt php-cli php-gd php-curl php-mysql
#    && chown -R www-data:www-data /srv/jumbledown

COPY . /srv/jumbledown

#    RUN docker-php-ext-install mbstring pdo pdo_mysql \
#    && chown -R www-data:www-data /srv/jumbledown
```

Dockerfile for nginx

```
FROM nginx:1.12

# ADD ./.docker/site.conf /etc/nginx/conf.d/
ADD ./.docker/nginx/default.conf /etc/nginx/conf.d/
```

default.conf

```
upstream appUpstream {
    server app;
}

server {
    listen      80;

    index index.php

    server_name jumbledown.com www.jumbledown.com;

    client_max_body_size 30M;

    location / {
        proxy_pass        http://appUpstream/;
        proxy_redirect                  off;
        proxy_buffering                 off;
        proxy_request_buffering         off;
        proxy_http_version 1.1;
        proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
        proxy_set_header Connection "upgrade";
    }
}
```

Ideally, I'd like to be able to run `docker-compose up --build` and then type a URL into my browser and see the Laravel boilerplate front page pop up.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the nginx as a reverse proxy link it to the other containers and use an Upstream to access the container
so the changes should be  :

First the docker-compose :

```
   .
   .
   .
  webserver:
    image: nginx:1.12
    container_name: webserver
    links:
      - app    
    ports:
      - "80:80"
      - "443:443"
    networks:
      - draft-network
    volumes: # mount custom config at runtime
      - ./docker/nginx/default.conf:/etc/nginx/conf.d/default.conf
    restart: unless-stopped
    tty: true
```

the default.conf should be :

```
upstream appUpstream {
   server app;
}


server {
    listen      80;
    server_name exemple.com;
    client_max_body_size 30M;
     location / {
      proxy_pass        http://appUpstream/;
      proxy_redirect                  off;
      proxy_buffering                 off;
      proxy_request_buffering         off;
      proxy_http_version 1.1;
      proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
      proxy_set_header Connection "upgrade";
    }
```

here's a ref that can help you : 
https://docs.nginx.com/nginx/admin-guide/web-server/reverse-proxy/

Comment: Hi there, thanks for the answer and the documentation.  I'm working through it but it's heavy going!  I've updated the question above, as I have made some progress.

Comment: Building an image docker just to mount the default conf  is bad  , you  should mount the volume when the image starts , i edit the answer so you can see how to mount a file

Comment: Thank you.  There are a LOT of options to work through!

Comment: thank you , yes there a lot of  options you can use , keep it up  :)